# Reverse .toggle() in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to toggle a div when pressing a button.
Currently I have this:

```
$("#reportOptions").toggle("fast");
```

But when I first click the button, it sets the div to:

```
display: none;
```

And when I click again:

```
display: block;
```

Which is fine, but I want the first click to be style block, so the reverse the toggle. 
How can I do this? Jquery.com does not explain this and every post on SO is about reversing the animations but not about the boolean.

I already tried to set the initial HTML to `display: none;` but the animation cancels in a weird way (only for the first click) if I do it like that.

Comment: Why not $("#reportOptions").toggle("hide");

Comment: `toggle` check current style and show in was hide

Comment: @LearningMode Because it needs to unhide the first click, and hide the second and so on and so forth.

Comment: @Grundy I know, but I cancels the animation in a weird way if I set the default HTML to "style: none;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All [`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) does is switch between `display: none` and `display: block`. If you want your first click to set the element to `display: block`, initialize the element's style with `display: none`. Here's a demo:

```css
#reportOptionsHidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Initially visible</h2>
<div id="reportOptionsVisible">Here are the initially visible report options</div>
<button onclick="$('#reportOptionsVisible').toggle('fast')">Toggle</button>

<h2>Initially hidden</h2>
<div id="reportOptionsHidden">Here are the initially hidden report options</div>
<button onclick="$('#reportOptionsHidden').toggle('fast')">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I forgot the mention in my intial post that I tried that already, but that the animation cancels in a weird way if I do it like that.

Comment: Can you describe the "weird way" or post a gif? This should work just fine; maybe you've got something else getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

Toggle to hide and show can be use like this.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="reportOptions" style="display:none;">
this is just test
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="fun_toggle()" value="Toggle">
<script type="text/javascript">
function fun_toggle(){
   $("#reportOptions").toggle("hide");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just start the div in CSS off with the opposite display that the first toggle should take you to.